# maven cannot create archetype org.fusesource.scalate.tooling:scalate-archetype-jersey

Tags: scala, maven, scalate

Using a clean installation of maven 3.0.1:

```
> mvn archetype:generate

Choose a number or apply filter: 
  461: remote -> org.fusesource.scalate.tooling:scalate-archetype-jersey (An archetype which creates an empty Scalate web application)

Choose org.fusesource.scalate.tooling:scalate-archetype-jersey version: 
   11: 1.5.3-scala_2.8.2


> mvn clean install

[ERROR] Plugin org.fusesource.scalate:maven-scalate-plugin:1.5.3-scala_2.8.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact org.fusesource.scalate:maven-scalate-plugin:jar:1.5.3-scala_2.8.2 in central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Why is so?
do I need to a repository or something?

Comment: https://www.assembla.com/spaces/scalate/tickets/291#/activity/ticket:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the archetypes have been updated since then, and now there the following two ones:

477: remote -> org.fusesource.scalate.tooling:scalate-archetype-jersey_2.10 (An archetype which creates an empty Scalate web application)
478: remote -> org.fusesource.scalate.tooling:scalate-archetype-jersey_2.9 (An archetype which creates an empty Scalate web application)

I tried with scalate-archetype-jersey_2.9 and it passes the "mvn clean install" command.